# GWT and Hibernate NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: hibernate, gwt, noclassdeffounderror

When i try to make an RPC call to the server i get the following error message

** WebModule[/ProjectName]Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/cglib/proxy/Enhancer**

Is this any classpath issue?or do i need to include any lib file or something in my project?

I tried searching for a solution but could not find one online.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate extends your entity classes so that gwt cannot serialize them, meaning you need to separate classes for sending the data over an rpc.

You will find more info on [this page](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/webtoolkit/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy .jar file that contains net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer class to war/web-inf/lib directory. Apparently, it's must be hibernate jar.